# Errors when plotting $\operatorname{Re}\sum_{n=1}^{200} \frac{(a\ln x)^n}{n!\, n\zeta (n+1)}$ in $x$

Tags: plotting, graphics, special-functions

Let $a=1/2-30.424876126i$ ($i^2=-1$). Then trying to plot
$$\operatorname{Re}\sum_{n=1}^{200} \frac{(a\ln x)^n}{n!\, n\zeta (n+1)}$$
in $x$ leads to a very inaccurate jaggy graph possibly caused by some floating point errors:

```
a:=1/2-30.424876126I
f[x_]:=Sum[(a Log[x])^n/(n! n Zeta[n+1]),{n,1,200}]
Plot[Re[f[x]],{x,1,5}]
```

[image: graph]
The beginning of the graph is good, though. How can the errors be mitigated?

Comment: If your value of a is supposed to be a zero of the zeta function, have you also tried including more decimal values?

Comment: @zeattledave Combining SetPrecision and WorkingPrecision solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use higher [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html):

```
f[u_] = Sum[u^n/(n n! Zeta[1 + n]), {n, 1, 200}];
a = SetPrecision[1/2 - 30.424876126 I, ∞];  (* make exact value *)
Plot[Re[f[a*Log[x]]], {x, 1, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

[image]

Comment: The option `PlotPoints -> 100` instead of `WorkingPrecision -> 100` works too. BTW, the plot is different from yours.